# What will be the parameters of HD image for uploading

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I want to check whether user is uploading HD image or normal image. Based on what parameters I can know that image is HD. I want to validate to upload only HD images.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: What do you define as HD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var image = new Image();
image.src = <image data or link>
```

Now, you can use the width and height methods exposed by the Image class to get the width and height respectively to check for "HD"

i.e. checking for 1080P

```
if(image.width != 1920 || image.height != 1080)
{
    alert("Image is not 1080P");
}
```